# In c#, How to save an image file fetched using Directory.GetFiles() into another location?

Tags: c#

I used the following code to fetch image from disk.

The `ImageName` variable contains part of required files name.

```
Image ImageFile = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
                           .Where(x => x.Contains(ImageName))
                           .Select(Image.FromFile)
                           .First();
```

Provided with destination path, how do I save to to my destination with the same filename?

Comment: Do you mean [ImageFile.Save()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First off your code shouldn't compile.  `FromFile` needs at least one parameter.  You probably need something like this:

```
Image ImageFile = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
                           .Where(x => x.Contains(ImageName))
                           .Select(x => Image.FromFile(x))
                           .First();
```

Then to save it, as was mentioned, use the `Image.Save` method.  Something like this:

```
string newDestinationPath = @"C:\MyFolder\" + ImageName;
ImageFile.Save(newDestinationPath);
```

In looking at your code, I realized that if ImageName isn't a proper file name, this won't work.  Here's a revision that corrects that:

```
var ImageFile = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
                    .Where(x => x.Contains(ImageName))
                    .Select(x => new { filename = Path.GetFileName(x), image = Image.FromFile(x) })
                    .First();
string newDestinationPath = @"C:\Temp\test1\" + ImageFile.filename;
ImageFile.image.Save(newDestinationPath);
```

This revision casts ImageFile as an anonymous type that contains an image and the filename it came from.  This allows the 2 to remain together and allow a proper file name to be used regardless of the search string being used.  Also this assumes that each query will return at least one item.  If not, additional code will be required to check if the query is empty.